# Testing Lombok annotations with Junit

Tags: java, junit, lombok

I have a simple Java program which uses the Lombok Annotation - `@Builder`. 
I am testing my code using junit and everytime I run my unit tests, my coverage is always below 50% inspite of the fact that I am testing my entire code.

I looked into the junit generated code coverage and I saw that it was the Lombok annotation which was making the coverage drop.

I see something like:

```
toString() - 0%
build() - 0%
MyMethod.MyMethodBuilder() - 0%
```

How do I test these methods for the `@Builder` annotation? Or the only way to improve coverage is to exclude those from the test coverage?

Comment: I'd rather go the other way and exclude the generated code from the coverage report. What are you using there?

Comment: JaCoCo code coverage

Comment: Looks like this will only work partially: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520912/jacoco-exclude-generated-methods-using-it-with-lombok#31024230

Comment: This is definitely a good fix, but it puzzles me that there's no other solution other than excluding it from coverage.

Comment: Add an integration test that hits all generated code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting JaCoCo v0.8.0, you should create `lombok.config` file to the root of your project and add following content to it:

```
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

This will add `@Generated` annotation to Lombok generated files and JaCoCo will know that code coverage of such a code should be ignored.

[Credits to original author here](https://www.rainerhahnekamp.com/en/ignoring-lombok-code-in-jacoco/)

Answer (score 5):

Create **lombok.config** file and add texts below:

```
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

**config.stopBubbling = true** is telling Lombok that this is the root directory and that it shouldn’t search parent directories for more configuration files (you can have more than one lombok config files in different directories/packages).

**lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true** is telling Lombok to add the **@lombok.Generated** annotation to all generated methods.

Answer (score 0):

Decompile class which contains lombok annotation to see how lombok has generated source code and then write junits considering that code.
e.g. In case of @ToString, make explicit call to toString method on class object i.e. obj.toString();

Comment: Could you write an example?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use pl.pojo library to test the pojo model classes.